# Can I use databreak on MIPS(4kem) without JTAG?

Tags: mips, jtag

'MIPS32® 4KE® Processor Core Family Software User’s Manual' says that 4KE has the functionality of the hardware databreak for JTAG.
But I don't have JTAG.

I tried to read/write Databreak point registers on drseg from the software without JTAG. But I can't.
Shoud I need to switch to Debug-Mode? But I can't. How?

Can I use this function from the software without JTAG?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to execute a 'break' instruction to enter debug mode, only in debug mode, you can access the drseg registers.